# Was Isaiah loved 'from the pit', Isaiah 38:17?

Tags: hebrew, isaiah

I noticed that the KJV gives Isaiah 38:17 as :

> ... thou hast in love to my soul *delivered it* from the pit of corruption ... [KJV]

in which the addition, in italics, changes the meaning considerably. In the margin of the KJV is the following :

> [Heb.] thou hast loved my soul from the pit ... [KJV margin]

with which Green's Literal appears to agree :

> ... You loved my soul from the pit of destruction ... [GIB]

However Robert Young gives a completely different rendering from either of the above, as follows :

> ... thou hast delighted in my soul without corruption ... [YLT]

in which he employs no italics at all.

---

I can understand why the KJV margin and Green's translation could well be the real meaning, regarding the descent of Messiah into *sheol* :

> For thou wilt not leave my soul in hell (*sheol*); neither wilt thou suffer thine Holy One to see corruption [Psalm 16:10, KJV]
>
> Now that he ascended, what is it but that he also descended first into the lower parts of the earth ? [Ephesians 4:9, KJV.]

But I would like to see the text of Isaiah 38:17 confirmed before drawing the inference.

Can anyone shed light on this passage from the original Hebrew ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Gesenius

Gesenius<sup>1</sup> originally explained the phrase וְאַתָּה חָשַׁקְתָּ נַפְשִׁי מִשַּׁחַת בְּלִי in Isa. 38:17 as an example of a pregnant construction.<sup>2</sup>

> Mit prägnanter Construction Jes. 38,17: חָשַׁקְתָּ נַפְשִׁי מִשַּׁחַת בְּלִי du liebtest mich (und zogst mich) aus der Grube des Verderbens.
>
> with a pregnant construction [in] Isa. 38:17: חָשַׁקְתָּ נַפְשִׁי מִשַּׁחַת בְּלִי You loved me (and drew me) out of the pit of doom.

According to *Oxford English Dictionary*,<sup>3</sup>

> pregnant construction: n. *Grammar and Rhetoric* a construction in which more is implied than is expressed by the words.

#### HALOT

According to HALOT,<sup>4</sup> חָשַׁקְתָּ in Isa. 38:17 should be read as חָשַׁכְתָּ (*chashakhta*), “you darkened,” a conjugation of the verb חָשַׁךְ (*chashakh*).<sup>5</sup>

#### The Dead Sea Scrolls—1QIsa1 Scroll

[image: 1QIsa1, Isa. 38:17]

Although there are minor textual variants when compared to the Masoretic text, there is no substantial difference. Both manuscripts (M and 1QIsa1) contain חָשַׁקְתָּ (or its equivalent).<sup>6</sup>

The idea of a pregnant construction is supported by commentaries. McComiskey writes,<sup>7</sup>

[image]

---

#### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> Gesenius (German, 1st ed.), p. [343–344](https://books.google.com/books?id=TdBaAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA343#v=onepage&q&f=false), חָשַׁק
<sup>2</sup> OED online, “pregnant construction”
<sup>3</sup> Latin *constructio pregnans*
<sup>4</sup> Frankly, I may be misunderstanding HALOT; I also do not understand the basis for their assertion.
<sup>5</sup> On חָשַׁךְ (*chasakh*), see Gesenius (tr. Tregelles), p. [312](https://books.google.com/books?id=E80OAAAAQAAJ&pg=PR312#v=onepage&q&f=false) (CCCXII); HALOT, p. 361.
<sup>6</sup> The scribes of the Dead Sea Scrolls had a propensity for suffixing ה to words ending in /a/.
<sup>7</sup> McComiskey, p. [149](https://books.google.com/books?id=LJ2FESBD8BAC&lpg=PR1&pg=PA149#v=onepage&q&f=false)

#### References

Gesenius, Heinrich Friedrich Wilhelm. [*Gesenius’s Hebrew and Chaldee Lexicon to the Old Testament Scriptures.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=E80OAAAAQAAJ) Trans. Tregelles, Samuel Prideaux. London: Bagster, 1860.

Gesenius, Heinrich Friedrich Wilhelm. [*Hebräisch–Deutsches Handwörterbuch über die Schriften des Alten Testaments.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=TdBaAAAAcAAJ) Vol. 1. 1st ed. Leipzig: Vogel, 1810.

Koehler, Ludwig; Baumgartner, Walter. *A Hebrew and Aramaic Lexicon of the Old Testament.* Trans. Richardson, M. E. J. Ed. Baumgartner, Walter; Stamm, Johann Jakob. Leiden: Brill, 2002.

McComiskey, Thomas Edward. [*The Minor Prophets: An Exegetical and Expository Commentary.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=LJ2FESBD8BAC) Grand Rapids: Baker Academic, 2009.

The Digital Dead Sea Scrolls ([http://dss.collections.imj.org.il/](http://dss.collections.imj.org.il/isaiah))

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you.